# Etymology of "save" in the meaning of "except", "but", "unless"

Tags: etymology, prepositions, conjunctions

**Why** does *save* **also** mean

> other than : but or except "We had no hope save one."
>
> except for the fact that :  only —used with that
>
> but, except —used before a word often taken to be the subject of a clause
>
> "Little is known about his early years save that he left home when he was very young."

This question is specifically about the **origin/etymology** of *this particular* meaning of the word.

Merriam-Webster just says

> Middle English *sauf*, from Anglo-French *salf*, *sauf*, from Latin *salvus* safe, healthy; akin to Latin *solidus* solid, Greek *holos* whole, safe, Sanskrit *sarva* entire

I am able to connect *solid* or *whole* or *entire* with the common meaning of *safe*/*save*, but how is it connected with *except*/*but*/*unless*?

Supplementary question: is this usage of *save* now archaic? M-W doesn't say so, but I have never heard it used in a live speech.

Comment: Well I know _sauf_ is French for _except_, probably for a similar reason.

Comment: Given at [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=save).

Comment: @Edwin Etymonline doesn't really give anything much. It just says that the English development parallels the French and gives examples of both meanings. It doesn't answer this question, which is how you get from the literal meaning ‘safe’ to the prepositional meaning ‘except for’.

Comment: @Janus In the light of your extended answer, I'll retract the close vote, though the brief Etymonline statement should have been quoted by OP.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your last question first: no, *save* in this sense is not archaic. It’s not as common as *except*, but it occurs in natural speech, especially as part of the phrase *save for*.

As to why *save (for)* means ‘except (for)’, that is a relatively long story.

Originally, in mediaeval French, *sauf/salf* (masculine) and *sauve/salve* (feminine) were used as adjectives meaning ‘whole, intact, safe’ only. All the way back since Latin, this adjective was frequently used in an absolute manner to mean ‘with [X] safe/whole/intact’: in Latin, this was an absolute ablative, and you had expressions like *salvā fīdē* ‘with your faith intact/without violating your faith’. In French, where the ablative was long gone, the absolute usage was simply just the plain form, but still originally inflected to fit the number and gender of the noun it qualified: *sauf sun ordre* ‘with his order intact/not disobeying his order’ vs. *sauve sa grace* ‘with his grace *or* lordship intact/not disobeying *or* disrespecting (etc.) his grace *or* lordship’.

During Middle French, the inflection to match the noun modified started to be lost, and the masculine singular form *sauf* was used, becoming more and more preposition- or conjunction-like.

The meaning also shifted: from indicating that something was kept intact and unviolated, it came to be used as a polite way of expressing disagreement, similar to *pace* in modern academia: it meant something like ‘while not meaning any violation towards X’, ‘if X will excuse me saying so’, etc.

From this meaning came a more abstract meaning of the object of *save*, which was now clearly a preposition. This object now started being considered as having been removed from harm’s way, having been taken apart to avoid violation or unwholesomeness, as it were. The thing that was ‘safe/save’ in this sense was therefore now simply considered as not being included in the main group. The overlapping sense can be envisioned in an example phrase like “All the men were killed in the war, save one”: the one man is removed from his group of belonging (“all the men”) and is considered apart, immune to the effects of the sentence upon that group. He is both literally safe from being killed in the war and ‘safe’ from whatever happens in the sentence, so to speak.

This nuance of meaning was probably blurred out quite quickly, and only the notion of the object being seen as something that had been taken out of its group and was seen as an exception survived, which is basically the meaning both *save* and *except* has today.

*[This answer is based on and fleshed out from the definitions and etymological notes given in the [OED article for](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/171457)* save *(requires subscription).]*

Comment: WOW! :) And you deserve extra credit for the sentence “All the men were killed in the war, save one” :)

Comment: I edited your post marginally and apologise for any offense. I simply wished to clarify {the object of *save*} vs *save*, in that long sentence. Please feel free to refine.

Comment: Also, did you intend that length for your last independent clause  (`and only the notion of the object ...`) ?

Answer (score -4):

I had someone use "save for" in an email recently. And I thought it was odd.  I actually wasn't sure what it meant.  And last Sunday at church, we sang the hymnal "Be thou my vision" and it uses the term "save for" also.  But it's a really old hymn.  So, yes, I find it archaic.

Comment: The OP is asking for the entomology for this usage. Was that hymn the first example of of using "save for" to mean "except"?, or can you find earlier examples?

Comment: "Save for" as "except" is not uncommon at all, although it's certainly more common in writing that is more formally written.

Comment: I see you're the victim of a question that needs some work. The question really shouldn't be "do you perceive this usage of save as archaic". The reason is that Stack Exchange is for expert answers, not for polling, or asking for opinions or discussion. The downvotes on your answer reflect that what we're looking for is "expert" or "right" answers. We do have a great place for discussion, though -- our [chat].

Comment: @MetaEd I wouldn't recommend chat. Some users behave rudely and cruelly when they think they are among friends.

Comment: http://www.be-thou-my-vision.com/be_thou_my_vision_lyrics_words.html uses *save that* not *save for*

Comment: @MetaEd How shall we measure the "archaicity" objectively? I am not talking about how *old* the word is, but whether it is nowadays archaic. Isn"t the notion itself defined just by the perception of the majority?

Comment: @HonzaZidek Written texts are studied to find out how the usage patterns change. Here is one article about it. https://qz.com/1061782/the-complex-process-that-dictionaries-use-to-decide-which-words-are-obsolete/

Comment: @MetaEd: An interesting link, but...
1. *To be labeled Obs., the general rule “is that if we can find no quotation evidence for an item that dates from 1930 or later, we label the item as obsolete.”* - this is quite(!) a conservative approach :)

Comment: 2. *Also, novelists often make an effort to use such unusual vocabulary.* It may be pretty difficult to take these archaic-on-purpose usages into account when searching if a word has not been used since 1930 :)

Comment: @HonzaZidek I think we can agree the lexicographer's job is not an easy one.

Comment: @MetaEd: yes. Still, their definition of *obsolete* is very far from how I perceive the notion :)